# How can i access HttpContext.Request.Cookie from a different thread than UI Thread in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, cookies, httpcontext

I have a C# web application where there's a need to access the HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookie and HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie in order get and set the cookie value, where the HttpContext.Current object shall be accessed from a new thread, as the value returned from a code that runs inside the thread shall be assigned to the Cookie,
How can i access the HttpContext.Current object from that new thread?

Please advise,

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Explain a bit more in detail what you want to do so that people can propose a better solution

Comment: Why are you doing multi threading in an ASP.NET app in the first place?